# shell changing and login into ubuntu system

Tags: linux, ubuntu, unix

I have loggined into ubuntoo system using username-root and password-root.

after running some commands i run `chsh -s /bin/csh root` to change its shell.

but next time when i tried to logging into Ubuntu system with username-root and passsword-root, it is showing "Access denied" and is unable to login.

can anybody give any hint that what to do for login again?

Comment: Normally when you install ubuntu, you define an account as a sudo account - that you can use sudo to execute root level commands.  Can you still log in as this user?

Comment: Do you have any other user name you can login as?  If so, you could then try to use the "su" command to fix things as well:  http://www.linfo.org/su.html

Answer (score 0):

I would try [Boot to Single User Mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/132965/how-do-i-boot-into-single-user-mode-from-grub) and then edit `/etc/passwd` to change root's shell back to `/bin/bash` or check the file permissions on `/bin/csh` to see if it is not executable.